# how to insert data from textboxes into mysql database in java-netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I am new to programming and i am trying to make an small Java swing application using netbeans IDE and i have designed the Form and created an table too i used the following code to insert data into database from the form but i am getting many errors please help me to correct this code:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class db
{
  static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb";
  static final String USER="root";
  static final String PASS="toor";

  Connection conn = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
  static final String d_unit=jTextField2.getText();
  static final String d_name=jTextField3.getText();
  static final String d_dob=jDateChooser2.getText();
  //static final String d_gender="gender";
  static final String d_age=jTextField4.getText();
  static final String d_doorno=jTextField5.getText();
  static final String d_street=jTextField6.getText();
  static final String d_vc=jTextField7.getText();
  static final String d_district=jTextField8.getText();
  static final String d_pin=jTextField9.getText();
  static final String d_phone=jTextField10.getText();
  static final String d_mail=jTextField11.getText();
  static final String d_occupations=jTextField12.getText();
  try
  {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     stmt.executeUpdate("insert into donors (unit,name,dob,age,doorno,street,vc,district,pin,phone,mail,occupation) values('"+d_unit+"','"+d_name+"','"+d_dob+"','"+d_age+"','"+d_doorno+"','"+d_street+"','"+d_vc+"','"+d_district+"','"+d_pin+"','"+d_phone+"','"+d_mail+"','"+d_occupations+"')");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted Successfully!");
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {     }

   }
```

Comment: @Gerret I think the problem here is compile time errors.

Comment: You're inserting all values as `VARCHAR`. Are these actually defined as varchars in database? For example `doorno` or `age` look like integers. I would also strongly recommend use `PreparedStatement` instead `Statement`. See [Using PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @Axel well that questions explain that not very good! And the header is actully not the topic... but ok ^^

Comment: what is stacktrace?? @ Gerret

Answer (score 3):

You may not use the `final String` because, then you can't modify these Strings, and the other code is correct, but i think you can use the `?` in the line:

```
String sql="INSERT INTO ´donors´ (unit,name) VALUES (?,?)";
    //put the rest of the sentence
      try {
        PreparedStatement pdt = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pdt.setString(1, jTextField2.getText();
        pdt.setString(2, jTextField3.getText();
        //put the rest of the code
        int n1=pdt.executeUpdate();
      if(n1>0)
      {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted Successfully!");
      }
      }catch (SQLException ex) { }
```

Well, that's the largest way, but the most correct. I hope this helps.

Comment: I TRIED YOUR method for inserting data into mysql table but still couldn't insert the data i am getting many errors here is my complete code pastie can you please help me to fix the problem ??

here is my pastie [link](http://pastebin.com/d0D2S0ru)

Comment: ok but i need the lines where you have the errors and the kind of errors exceptions

Comment: Here is the lines which are leading to error and the corresponding error
static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";/*Illegal start of expression*/
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");/*illegal start of type*/

          conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);/*cannot find symbol*/

stmt = conn.createStatement();/*Unreported Sql Exception must be caught or thrown*/

PreparedStatement pdt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);/*Unreported Sql Exception must be caught or thrown*/

pdt.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());/*Identifier expected*/
still

Comment: Your problem in that code is you're declaring variables as `static final` inside this method: `private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)`. That's not correct. Take a look to [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for a better understanding of using `static` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String itemCode = txtItemCode.getText();
    String itemName = txtItemName.getText();
    String unitPrice = txtUnitPrice.getText();
    String qty = txtQty.getText();
    String query = "insert into items values ('"+itemCode+"','"+itemName+"','"+unitPrice+"','"+qty+"')";
    System.out.println(query);


    try {
        Connection c = DBClass.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

// DBClass

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Nadun
 */
public class DBClass {

    static private Connection  connection;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
        if(connection == null){
            //JDBC
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stock", "root", "123");
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks alright. Maybe the trouble is on your mysql database?

Check the data type of your row in mysql, if your data type in the current row is "int", then it should be like this

```
try
{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
 stmt = conn.createStatement();
 stmt.executeUpdate("insert into donors (name, age) values('"+d_name+"',,'"+Integer.valueOf(d_age.getText().toString())+"')");
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Inserted Successfully!");
 }
catch(Exception e){     }

}
```

You should be careful with data types. If your mysql row is int type then in your java you should give it int time as well.

I guess your data type of "name" row is text that use string, and your data type of "age" row is int?

I check your code is giving a string value from your java to your int mysql row. that's the error.

So you should convert the string to the int first

```
Integer.valueOf(d_age.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try proceeding like this for simplicity and less error-prone

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO donors(unit,name,dob,age,doorno,street,vc,district,pin,phone,mail,occupation) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```